# What's the highest number of unique Pals I can get from a single starting breeding pair?

Tags: palworld

Learned that Pals breeding can result in new species, wanted to try a minimum catches, full Paldeck challenge.

So what's the breeding pair to start the challenge with?

Comment: Each pair of Pals will only ever result in a single offspring type. I assume your challenge would mean the parents can be bred with the offspring? And likewise, assuming that wild eggs aren't a factor?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Yep, that's one reason I don't like "breeding pair" for the question because it doesn't involve the offspring breeding. And yeah, no Wild Eggs unless they're the only way to get some Pals, because apparently some Pals can only be bred from the same species.

Comment: Gotcha. This should be relatively straightforward, just gotta churn through some data.

Comment: Thank you for changing the title! 

Comment: @AdamRaichu - You want to notify RavenDreamer for that. heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer: 127

Breeding in Palworld is not random -- for a given pair of pals, you will always get the same species of offspring.

The actual mechanics are kinda persnickety with exceptions, but the basic gist is that each Pal has a "Breeding Power" value, and when two Pals breed, their Breeding Power gets averaged to determine their offspring. This value goes from 10 (**Blazamut**) to 1500 (**Chikipi**), and *generally* correlates with rarity.

This averaging means that if you breed two weak / common pals together, you'll get those same weak common pals, but also that if you breed two strong / rare pals together, you'll get only other strong / rare pals. It serves to follow, then, that the best way to ensure a wide variety of offspring is to have one parent with high breeding power, and one parent with low breeding power.

...which is just a roundabout way of saying **Blazamut x Chikipi** will eventually get you to every pal in the game, minus the 5 pals that only breed true with their own species (**Jetragon**, **Frostallion**, **Necromus**, **Paladius**, and **Jormuntide Ignis**).

The **Blazamut** isn't strictly necessary, but the **Chikipi** is; **Frostallion**, **Frostallion Noct**, **Jetragon**, **Necromus**, **Paladius**, and **Suzaku Aqua** will also (eventually) get you the complete* Paldex.

(I came to this result programmatically, and am in the process of hosting the code on github.)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be something like that. I just didn't have the brain to go through the math myself! Thanks so much! ... So I should use a Frostallion x Chikipi so I don't have to get another Frostallion to breed true?

Comment: @Malady Sounds right to me!

Comment: Actually, isn't Blazamut necessary too, otherwise the 60 Breeding Power Nitewing is impossible, right? At least according to a Google Sheet I read?

Comment: My program and the [Genshin lab calculator](https://genshinlab.com/palworld-breeding-combos-calculator/) both say you can get a Nitewing from Frostallion + Blazehowl. Where are you getting your data from? Mine says Nitewing is breeding power 420. Shadowbeak is breeding power 60, and is one of the 5 Pals who can only be hatched from unique parents (thereby ignoring breeding power entirely)

Comment: Yep, got confused with Shadowbeak. Thanks!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Where did you get your results, the calculator states "Lyleen" and "Menasting" make a "Lyleen Noct", but that's wrong, I tried it and got a few "Penking" instead